# GROUP and COUNT in SPARQL

Tags: count, grouping, sparql, wikidata

I am using WikiData SPARQL Endpoint to search for two entities: museums (`wd:Q33506`) and libraries (`wd:Q7075`) that have instagram and twitter accounts and from which country they are from. I am trying to count them and group them by country.

```
SELECT ?item ?instagram ?twitter ?countryLabel (COUNT(?country) AS ?ccount) WHERE {
  { ?item (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q33506. }
  { ?item (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q7075. }
  ?item wdt:P2003 ?instagram.
  ?item wdt:P2002 ?twitter.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country. }
}
GROUP BY ?country
ORDER BY ?ccount
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main error is:

> Query is malformed: Bad aggregate

From [11.4 Aggregate Projection Restrictions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregateRestrictions):

> In a query level which uses aggregates, only expressions consisting of aggregates and constants may be projected, with one exception. When `GROUP BY` is given with one or more simple expressions consisting of just a variable, those variables may be projected from the level.

Thus, your query should be:

```sql
SELECT ?countryLabel (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?ccount) WHERE {
  { ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q33506. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q7075. }
  ?item wdt:P2003 ?instagram.
  ?item wdt:P2002 ?twitter.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country. }
}
GROUP BY ?countryLabel ORDER BY DESC(?ccount)
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FcountryLabel%20%28COUNT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fccount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ33506.%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ7075.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2003%20%3Finstagram.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fccount%29%0A)

I've also added `UNION`, `DISTINCT` and replaced `?country` with `?item` in the projection.

Note that libraries and museums that have *both* Instagram and Twitter accounts are counted.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was trying to use empty GROUP. Then I should be able to add as many UNIONs to add other organisations

Comment: @Trinker please use `VALUES` instead of multiple `UNION` if you want to process a list of URIs